# Error message when trying to run npm start in React app folder

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, node.js

I am working through a ZTM Web dev course and during the section on React I started receiving an 'Error' message. I am receiving this message when trying to use 'npm start' inside of a React app folder. I am using VS Code on windows 11. Please let me know if there is any other info I can provide to be helpful.

Starting the development server...

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:401:16)
    at handleParseError (C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:449:10)
    at C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:481:5
    at C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:342:12
    at C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:401:16)
    at C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:433:10
    at C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:308:13
    at C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at C:\Users\cosby\robofriends\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:51:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

Node.js v20.5.1

PS I followed instructions provided by chat gpt and a few other sources on how to resolve the problem but none of those solutions have worked.

PS I followed instructions provided by chat gpt and a few other sources on how to resolve the problem but none of those solutions have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run command in your terminal:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

then run:

```
npm start
```

Comment: Thanks! this appears to have resolved the issue. I am still getting a brief error that appears when i 'npm start' the app but then it disappears as soon as the app is compiled and running. can get a screen shot because it flashes so briefly.